# How do i connect to server in ubuntu using .ppk file?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to use ubuntu Places -> Connect to Server . but i am not having password but have the .ppk file of the password.

Answer (score 2):

Either install PuTTY and add a path to the key for the connection:

[alt text http://wazem.dyndns.org/temp/blog/id-rsa-to-ppk/putty.jpg](http://wazem.dyndns.org/temp/blog/id-rsa-to-ppk/putty.jpg)

Or [convert](http://blog.padraigkitterick.com/2007/09/16/using-putty-ssh-keys-with-openssh-on-ubuntu/) your PuTTY ppk key into "normal" OpenSSH keys and just use the regular OpenSSH client.

Comment: BTW why the convertion is needed? It's the same RSA/DSA algo! :)

Comment: Yes, same algorithm, but different ways to store the key. Openssh format mandates that the key be on one line, while the putty format has the key broken up across multiple lines.